# Php how set data in string using html id

Tags: javascript, php, html, domdocument

I have long html text. Pass it from js to php. I need change ID content with my text.

I tried did it like this:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($codeText);
$html->getElementById('second_head')->nodeValue = $leadAddressTemplate;
$html->getElementById('rechnung_div')->nodeValue = $rehnungTemplate;
$res = $html->saveHTML();
```

It works but have problem - my <> chars system replaces to `&lt;` and `&gt;` and system adds `<html><body>` to my text.

How can I fix it? Maybe there are some flags for it?

For example, input is :

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="invoice-products" width="100%">
        <div id="rechnung_div"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And it try do it:

```
$html->getElementById('rechnung_div')->nodeValue = '<p>It is rechnung</p>';
```

As result i have this:

```
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="invoice-products" width="100%">
        <div id="rechnung_div">&lt;p&gt;It is rechnung&lt;/p&gt;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I can set for example

element:

```
    $appended = $html->createElement('p', 'It is rechnung');
    $html->getElementById('rechnung_div')->nodeValue = '';
    $rechnung_div->appendChild($appended);
```

But how insert table , for example like this?

```
   <table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="width: 40%;vertical-align: baseline;"><h1 id="invoice_type">Rechnung</h1>
            <p id="invoice_title">gtrgtrgrtgtr</p></td>
        <td style="width: 60%;text-align: right;vertical-align: bottom;"><h1>&nbsp;</h1><p id="invoice_nummer"></p></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't do it with appendChild() function

Comment: Please give us examples of input, desired output, and actual output. Make sure to either use code blocks or backticks so that HTML and HTML entities render correctly in your question.

Comment: But if those template vars contain HTML text that you are trying to append into the document, you can't just do that. You have to parse those as separate documents, get the relevant root node or nodes, and use [`appendChild()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) to add them to the selected elements.

Comment: You should do `$html->loadHTML($codeText, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` to prevent auto adding of doctype, html, body elements. As for the HTML entities encoding, you probably need to use regex (preg_replace) to revert it.

Comment: @Sammitch added some examples

Comment: @icecub thanks it works for remove not necessary code

Comment: @Sammitch I tried it : `$rechnung_div = $html->getElementById('rechnung_div');
    $appended = $html->createElement('p', 'It is rechnung');
    $rechnung_div->appendChild($appended);` But it doesn't replace element content, it added to the end. And what if i need just put big ready text? For example table or big div? How can i do it?

Comment: Please check my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Rolling together the notes from the comments:

```php
$parent = <<<_E_
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="invoice-products" width="100%">
        <div id="rechnung_div"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
_E_;

$template = <<<_E_
<p>I am a template</p>
_E_;

$temp = new DOMDocument();
$temp->loadHTML($template, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
// get the document's root element
$temp_root = $temp->documentElement;

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($parent, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
// import the template into the current document
$node = $html->importNode($temp_root, true);
$html->getElementById('rechnung_div')->appendChild($node);

echo $html->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="invoice-products" width="100%">
        <div id="rechnung_div"><p>I am a template</p></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. For what you use <<<_E_ ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc